# how to convert EJS to handlebars?

Tags: for-loop, handlebars.js, nodes, ejs

is it possible to use both ejs and handlebars in the same project? or do i need to change the ejs to handlebars? This is a piece of the code that needs to be changed, can someone help me?

```
<ul>
        <% for(var i=0; i < discussions.length; i++) { %>
            <li><a href="/discussion/<%= i %>"><%= discussions[i].question %></a></li>
        <% } %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#each discussion}}
<li><a href="/discussion/... </a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may solve the problem at hand, more explanation is necessary to help future users of the site understand how to apply this solution to their situation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, No. You can use only one view engine. If your project is on handlebars, then stick to handlebars. If it's on ejs, stick with ejs. And for the following code to be converted into handlebars, this will do:

```
{{#each discussion}}
<li><a href="/discussion/... </a></li>
{{/each}}
```